# Javascript/Jquery: How to paginate a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, pagination

I would like to know the suitable method to add pagination for my scenario: I using the "$('body').append(htmlText);" to display the items within the JSON object. How to add a pagination that display 1 item for each page depending on how many got in the JSON?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script>
    var data = [{
                 "name": "Bebe",
                 "lastname": "Rexha",
                 "description": "Young and beautiful",
                 "producer": "ABC Music",
                 "users_name": "BebeLove",
                },
                {
                  "name": "Katy",
                  "lastname": "Perry",
                  "description": "Cute and sweet",
                  "producer": "Kitty Music",
                  "users_name": "KittyCat",
                },
               ]

    var htmlText = '';

    for ( var key in data ) {
        htmlText += '<div class="div-conatiner">';
        htmlText += '<p class="p-name"> Name: ' + data[key].name + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="p-loc"> LastName: ' + data[key].lastname + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="p-desc"> Description: ' + data[key].description + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="p-created"> Produced by: ' + data[key].producer + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="p-uname"> Username: ' + data[key].users_name + '</p>';
        htmlText += '</div>';
    }

    $('body').append(htmlText);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you. Cheer :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)